# Changing the color of an SKSpriteNode image?

Tags: objective-c, colors, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

I was wondering if there was a way to change the color of an SKSpriteNode programmatically?? Say I have a texture for an SKSpriteNode that is a box that has a black outline and a white fill color. How would I be able to change the white fill color to a different color programmatically?? (I was thinking maybe a custom method that searched a texture for white pixels and then replace the pixels with a  different color) I don't even know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a color to `SKSpriteNode` and then use `colorBlendFactor`, here is an example:

```
image.color = [UIColor greenColor];
image.colorBlendFactor = 0.5;
```